# Installing PHP 5.5 on 15.10

Tags: php, 15.10

I've tried multiple ways to install PHP 5.5 including various PPAs etc however every time it always installs 5.6.

Is there a reliable way to to install without having to compile from source?

Answer (score -1):

Use the ppa:ondrej/php5 repository. It only has php 5.5 as you can see from https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75 page.

Comment: Tried that and it still goes ahead and installs 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1

Comment: Are you sure you have no other php repository in your list?